# useEffect not always displaying the received message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io to create a simple chat application. I've spent a couple hours trying to debug this error with no avail.

When I try to display the received message with a useEffect hook it randomly works sometimes but is never consistent, which I'm assuming has to do with a socket connection issue? When I use "messageReceived" in my html the client always receives the correct message.

Additionally, when a client receives a message the live user count increases, which I do not understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Client-side Code**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001", {'force new connection': true});

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messageReceived, setMessageReceived] = useState("");
  const [LiveUsers, setLiveUsers] = useState("");
  
  let messages = document.querySelector('.messages');
  let textInput = document.querySelector('.textInput')


  /* Creates a new div which is then appended to the message box 
  each time a message is sent.
  */


  const sendMessage = () => {
    // Create a new child div each time a message is sent
    //setMessage(textInput.value);
    //let message_div = document.createElement("div");
    //message_div.innerHTML = textInput.value
    //message_div.className = "message_div"
    //messages.appendChild(message_div)
    //displayMessage(textInput.value)
    //socket.emit("send_message", message)
    //messages.textContent += `${messageReceived}\n`
    //messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
    let text = textInput.value
    displayMessage(text)
    socket.emit("send_message", text)
    textInput.value = ""
  }



  const displayMessage = (data) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.textContent = data
    messages.append(div)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      setMessageReceived(data)
      displayMessage(messageReceived)
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off("receive_message");
    };
  }, [socket, setMessageReceived]);

  socket.on("receive_users", (data) => {
    setLiveUsers(data);
  })


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2 className="text-white font-bold"style={{ color: "white", marginTop: 10}}> Online Users: {LiveUsers} </h2> 
      <pre className='messages'></pre>
      <input className="textInput text-gray-500 font-bold" style={{ height: 38, marginRight: 10, padding: 5, width: 1000}} placeholder='Message'/>
      <button id="name" className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" onClick={sendMessage}> Send </button>
      <h1>Message: {messageReceived}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Server-side code**

```
const express = require('express');

// Create instance of express library
const app = express();

const http = require("http");
const {Server} = require('socket.io');

// Prevents connection errors
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);


// Create WebSocket Server
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});


/* 
The client will make an HTTP request to switch
protocols and upgrade to WebSockets, which will establish the connection
to the WSS.
*/

let count = 0

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);
    count++;
    socket.emit("receive_users", count)
    socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
        // Sends message to all connnected clients excluding itself
        socket.broadcast.emit("receive_message", data);
        
    })
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("User Disconnected")
        count--;
        socket.removeAllListeners();
        socket.emit("receive_users", count)
    });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3001") 
});
```

Comment: You are using `socket.on("receive_users...` inside component body so it will run every time any state changes

Comment: You should never use `querySelector` in react. You should use list rendering instead of modifying the dom

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where should I place socket.on("receive_users... instead? Also, do you know why my useEffect hook is not working?